# C++11: std::vector::shrink_to_fit complexity

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, time-complexity

The [article at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) tells that the complexity of `std::vector::shrink_to_fit` is constant. As far as I know that is only possible if the elements are not moved, because if they are then the complexity is *n*. It also says that *All iterators, including the past the end iterator, are potentially invalidated.* which means that the moving of elements is a well defined possibility.

Is the article faulty? ... or is there any magic that I don't know about?

Comment: (The article was fixed rapidly. So the initial statement is false now.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The article <del>is</del> was faulty, I fixed it.

While the official standard doesn't say anything about the complexity of `std::vector::shrink_to_fit`, in N3376 they changed the wording, thereby fixing DR 2033:

23.3.6.3:

> `void shrink_to_fit();`
>
> *Requires*: `T` shall be `MoveInsertable` into `*this`.
>
> *Complexity*: Linear in the size of the sequence.

Comment: You might be quoting a draft - there is nothing in the C++11 standard about `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` complexity.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: yes, they changed it in N3376.

Comment: I see - interesting that they didn't add the wording for `basic_string<>::shrink_to_fit()` (yet?).

Comment: Maybe you should clarify that this is from a specific draft in your answer.